# TinyMCE, 2 times to Validate Even When Textbox Not Empty

Tags: javascript, validation, tinymce

Using TINYMce and validation, but it takes to two times to post and it doesn't matter whether the textarea is empty or not. I research this but wasn't able to find anything that worked. Below is code snippets.

Model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*Response Required")]
[UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
public string LibrarianResponse { get; set; }
```

View

```
<span style="color: red;font-weight: 700;">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LibrarianResponse)</span>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LibrarianResponse)
    </div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function ($) {
            $('#submit').click(function () {
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();});
            });
</script>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay Finally resolved this issue. My original code was nearly correct.

You'll notice that in my original question I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function ($) {
            $('#submit').click(function () {
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();});
            });
</script>
```

Also, I have this below for my `textarea`:

```
<span style="color: red;font-weight: 700;">
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LibrarianResponse)
</span>
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LibrarianResponse)
</div>
```

All I had to do was put `LibrarianResponse` (which was the `id` of the `textarea` in Google Chrome - spotted using dev tools) into the `.triggerSave` function.

So this worked. See below:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                    $('#submit').click(function () {
                        tinyMCE.triggerSave('#LibrarianResponse');

                    });
                });
```

Thanks to those who responded to my question. I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Please remember mark your post as answer. SO's goal is to have question answered. So if this worked for you, mark it as answer and following users will be able to easily find it and benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a small amount of time for TinyMCE to update the original (now hidden) inputs it operates on top of. You are doing that with `triggerSave`. However, the form submit is likely going to continue and run before `triggerSave` finishes. So do this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#submit').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        $(evt.target).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately it didn't work. The 'form' reference is something I am uncertain of.

Comment: Does your form have an id? If so, you can use just `$('#id').submit()`. I have run into this exact problem in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by having tinyMCE update the underlying textarea anytime the tinyMCE textarea changes:

```js
function tinyChanged(inst) {
    if (inst.isDirty()) {
        inst.save();
    }
}

tinymce.init({
    selector: "myTextArea",
    setup: function(ed) {
        ed.on("change", function () {
            tinyChanged(ed);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this. I added "id=myTextArea" to EditorFor area e.g., "new { id = "myTextArea"})  but it didn't work.